# Как написать функцию выводящую количество пробелов переданных в параметр?

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию, которая бы принимала в параметр число, и выводила количество пробелов этого числа?

Например: `space (3);` и выводится 3 пробела.
Я пробовал решить эту задачу с помощью цикла, но
выводился только один пробел.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `var result = ''.padStart(3);`

Comment: дак собственно какой вопрос то у вас возник? задачу свою вы описали, а про вопрос забыли. Вы не умеете писать цикл `while(len--){}` или делать конкатенацию строк `str += ' '` ? или что еще могло понадобится вам для решения?

Comment: Вероятно, это вопрос, который возник в процессе создания своего языка программирования.

Comment: Цикл while не работает и выводит только один пробел

Comment: @LasloDarckovsy, очевидно ты неверно его используешь. Покажи как именно, и тебе подскажут что поправить.

Comment: Не вижу причин для переоткрытия: кода, которым пытались решить задачу нет в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Если ориентироваться на современные браузеры, то есть метод у строк

```
" ".repeat(n);
```

Если требуется поддержка древних браузеров, то

```
Array(n + 1).join(" ");
```

Но этот код вернёт строчку из функции, а вот куда вы собрались выводить не ясно.

Если в консоль, то все просто:

```
function space (n){
    console.log(" ". repeat (n));
}
```